# create dispatch table inside class constructor in perl

Tags: perl, package, hashtable

I am trying to create dispatch table inside class constructor.Execution fails with below mentioned error.

Error:
  **Use of uninitialized value in subroutine entry at ../lib/Parser.pm .
Can't use string ("") as a subroutine ref while "strict refs" in use at ../lib/Parser.pm**.

Code:

```
package parser;

use strict;
use warning;

@packet = ("join","release","status");
#constructor 
sub new {
        my ($class) = shift;
        my $self = {
           _callerMDN => shift,
           _calleeList => shift,
           _serverIp => shift,
           _packetHandler => {
                join => \&joinHandler, #Dispatch table,variable "join" stores func reference
                release => \&releaseHandler, #variable "release" stores func reference
                status => \&statusHandler #variable "stores" stores func reference
                },
           _mdnHandler => {},

        };

        print ("The Server IP = $self->{_serverIp}\n") if ($debug);
        print ("CallerMDN = $self->{_callerMDN}\n") if ($debug);
        print ("TcpDump File Name = $self->{_tcpdumpFile}\n") if ($debug);

    bless( $self, $class );
    return $self;

}

sub start {
    my ($self,$data) = @_;
    if ($data ~= "Incoming Packet") {
         $self->{_packetHandler}->{$packet[0]}->($data);#**Error while calling "joinHandler" function**
    }
    elsif ($data ~= "Outgoing Packet"){
         $self->{_packetHandler}->{$packet[1]}->($data);#**Error while calling "releaseHandler" function**
    }
    else {
         $self->{_packetHandler}->{$packet[2]}->($data);#**Error while calling "statusHandler" function**
    } 

}

sub joinHandler {
    my ($self,$data) = @_;
    #parse packet
    print ("Incoming Packet parsed");
}

sub releaseHandler {
   my ($self,$data) = @_;
   #parse packet
   print ("Outgoing packet parsed");
}

sub statusHandler {
    my ($self,$data) = @_;
    #parse packet
    print ("status packet");
}
```

Please help me to understand and resolve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I see quite a few problems.

1. `use warning;` should be `use warnings;`
2. You forgot to `my @packet` at the top of your `package`
3. In `sub start` you have the `=~` backwards as `~=`. But it probably should be `eq` anyways.
4. `$debug` isn't declared anywhere.

You might find it useful to take advantage of `perl -c`, checks syntax(also runs BEGIN blocks too), when you run into problems.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at your conditional statements.
Try this:

```
$data eq "Incoming Packet"
```

There are some minor typos also:
use warnings;
and $debug variable is not initialized.

Hope that helps.